# MS Visio: how to add arrows to SVG path?

Tags: path, microsoft-visio, svg

I need your help.

I have an SVG file containing (among the others) the `line` and `path` objects.  What I need to do is to import this SVG into MS Visio and then add arrowheadss to these imported lines and paths.

The problem is that arrows are not applied to the imported paths while lines work fine.

The investigation of the ShapeSheet demonstrates that imported paths have no endpoints while the imported lines do have endpoints.

Maybe, the conversion of the imported path into the FreeForm will solve the issue, but I have no idea how to do it.

I will appreciate your help.